# VSCode uses different System Path's for Python with Run command and Debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Seemingly out of nowhere my python scripts in VS Code are no longer running correctly. None of the python packages I've installed are importing correctly anymore, getting a ModuleImport error. When I printed sys.path, and sys.version, I found that not only were the directories in path not correct, but the version of Python VS Code was trying to run was not the same as the version of Python the interpreter was set to use. The interpreter I had selected was using Python 3.9.7, but sys.version was printing Python 3.8. Even more strangely, when I ran the same code with the debugger, the directories printed by sys.path were magically correct, and the version of Python being run was suddenly correct again as well. In the end I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and all versions of Python on my system, but I'm still running into the same problem after creating a new environment, the only difference now is that the version of python being run is correct, but the path directories are not.

[Terminal output from Run:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZTgF.png)

[Terminal output from Debug:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShLbR.png)

In both cases the correct interpreter is selected, the only difference is using Run or Debug.

The only thing I can think of that may relate to the error is that I recently installed Linux on an external hard drive to dual boot from, and I installed Python on that as well. I'm not sure how that would cause this though.

Comment: Hard to say what your issue is without more info.
Are you using virtualenvs ? VSCode will use whatever interpreter you configured for your venv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the Python Extension update.

> Use conda run for conda environments for running python files and
> installing modules. ([#18479](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18479))

[changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog)(28 February 2022).

But it has some problems, I had submitted [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18665) on GitHub.

The debugger can take the correct python interpreter which you have selected in the VSCoe, while the command `conda run xxx` can not. It will persist in the **base** instead of the **NeoNatal** environment. **It can not select the sub environment under Anaconda3 envs**.

Execute `sys.executable` you will find it. If execute the python script directly in the terminal likes `python pythonFileName.py` instead of `conda run xxx` it will be working again.

**Update:**

Workaround:

1. [Set "python.terminal.activateEnvironment" to false in the settings.json.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18634#issuecomment-1060686997)
2. [Downgrade to the previous version of the extension which works fine(avoid `conda run`).](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18634#issuecomment-1061699266)
3. Try out the following VSIX which has the potential fix: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/suites/5578467772/artifacts/180581906, Use Extension: Install from VSIX command to install the VSIX.

Reason:

Conda has some problems:

[conda run -n MY-ENV python FILE.py uses the base interpreter instead of environment interpreter.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9587)

[Running using conda run inside already activated environment should be the same as running it outside](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11305)

[conda run does not remove base environment components from $PATH](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11174)

Comment: @LBurne Could you have a look at the update?

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:

1. Go to `VSCode` settings and go to `extensions`, and then find `Python`. Then find `Default Interpreter Path`. If the path it says is `python`, change it to your installation path.
2. Check your `PATH` and see if `Python` is in it.
3. Reinstalling `VSCode` or `Python`.